# Need assistance to fix console error saying 'Uncaught (in promise)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-redux

i'm trying to solve a problem in which i have to use a find() method and it's giving me an error

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstant';

const cartReducers = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;

      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);

      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return { ...state, cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item] };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducers;
```

This is my cartReducer.js file and i get an error in this file, when switching to a case 'CART_ADD_ITEM'

the error looks like this piece of code below

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
at cartReducers (cartReducers.js:8:1)
at combination (redux.js:560:1)
at E (<anonymous>:1:33326)
at I (<anonymous>:1:33613)
at <anonymous>:1:37893
at Object.dispatch (redux.js:288:1)
at e (<anonymous>:1:38904)
at index.js:20:1
at dispatch (redux.js:691:1)
at cartAction.js:7:1
```

Store.js file attached below

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import { productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducer.js';
import { productDetailsReducer } from './reducers/productReducer.js';
import cartReducers from './reducers/cartReducers.js';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducers,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItem: cartItemsFromStorage,
  },
};
const middleWare = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);

export default store;
```

and i have cartAction.js file below

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstant';

export const addToCart = (id, qnty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qnty,
    },
  });

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

and this file is the CartScreen.js, where the whole action is getting dispatched

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Message from '../components/Message.js';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Image,
  Form,
  Button,
  Card,
} from 'react-bootstrap';

import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartAction.js';
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const CartScreen = ({ match, location, history }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const productId = id;

  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const qnty = searchParams.get('qnty');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qnty));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qnty]);

  console.log(qnty);
};

export default CartScreen;
```

Comment: `state.cartItems` - is undefined

Comment: when creating a function i do have the state as and empty array in props, 

const cartReducers = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) =>{.......}

Comment: how are you calling `cartReducers`

Comment: it's getting combined in a reducer in 'Store.js' and then a 'cartAction.js' would call it when an action gets fired.

i have updated the code above
or if u want to have a look here, https://github.com/nav-j0t/Shop/tree/master/frontend/src

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `initialState` used in creating the store is overwriting the cart state and providing a malformed cart sub-state.

```js
const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItem: cartItemsFromStorage, // <-- cartItem, without an "s"
  },
};

...

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);
```

The store now contains `state.cart.cartItem` and so `state.cartItems` is undefined in the `cartReducers` reducer function.

## Suggested Solution

Ensure your initial state value matches any state subset, from root, of the state tree formed when combining all your reducers.

```js
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducers,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage, // <-- cartItems, with an "s"
  },
};

...

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare))
);
```